# AWS-ECS - Auto scaling with awsvpc mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am facing an issue while using AWS - ECS service.

I am launching my ECS cluster with 2 instances. I use EC2 service. Not Fargate. I am trying to use the `awsvpc` networking for the ECS containers. Morte info is [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-ecs-introduces-awsvpc-networking-mode-for-containers-to-support-full-networking-capabilities/).

For the container load balancing , target type is IP. It is not editable.

[image]

Now the problem is - Auto Scaling Group can not be created for this target group to scale the cluster.

[image]
How do you guys handle the situation?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because of awsvpc mode,awsvpc network mode is associated with an elastic
network interface, not an Amazon EC2 instance so you must choose IP. Here is what AWS said about AWVPC network mode .
[AWS_Fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html)

> Services with tasks that use the awsvpc network mode (for example,
>   those with the Fargate launch type) only support Application Load
>   Balancers and Network Load Balancers. Classic Load Balancers are not
>   supported. Also, when you create any target groups for these services,
>   you must choose **ip as the target type, not instance.** This is because
>   tasks that use the awsvpc network mode are associated with an elastic
>   network interface, not an Amazon EC2 instance.

Fargate do not to manage EC2 instances, the purpose of Fargate is **not to manage server** then why you need to attach auto-scaling? you can scale services.

> AWS Fargate is a technology that you can use with Amazon ECS to run
>   containers without having to manage servers or clusters of Amazon EC2
>   instances. **With AWS Fargate,** **you no longer have to provision,
>   configure, or scale clusters of virtual machines to run containers.**
>   This removes the need to choose server types, decide when to scale
>   your clusters, or optimize cluster packing.

[image]

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/aws-fargate-a-product-overview/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Simply leave out the load balancing configuration for the Auto Scaling group.

`awsvpc` creates a separate network interface whose IP address is registered to the Target Group. This target group has to be of the `ip-address` type.

Auto Scaling Groups use the `instance` target group type, that uses the default network interface of the EC2 instances.

Since the Task will get its own IP address, which is separate from the IP address of the EC2 instance, there is no need to configure load balancing for the EC2 instances themselves.

Comment: As 'a544h' has pointed, make sure that your AutoScalingGroup is not attached to the LoadBalancer's target group. Only register ECS service as the target which effectively register's service's containers as LB targets.